# Python Edgar asks for useragent

Tags: pandas, edgar, sec

I ran the following command:

```py
import edgar
import pandas as pd
edgar.download_index('/Users/myusername/Desktop/Desktop', 2010,skip_all_present_except_last=False)
```

It's throwing the following error asking for user_agent. Please clarify where can I get that useragent and guide if I am getting wrong on anything else? The error message is:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-95d304376aa1> in <module>
      1 import edgar
      2 import pandas as pd
----> 3 edgar.download_index('/Users/myusername/Desktop/Desktop', 2010,skip_all_present_except_last=False)

TypeError: download_index() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user_agent'
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [package documentation](https://pypi.org/project/python-edgar/), there is a `user_agent` parameter. This parameter is mandatory. The given example is "MyCompany edward@mycompany.com"

Try:

```
edgar.download_index('/Users/myusername/Desktop/Desktop', 2010, "your_name your@email.address", skip_all_present_except_last=False)
```